# Issue with React development server refresh. How do i solve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Welcome.

I just started to learn ReactJS, for the **first** few attempts, **it was okay**, but **since a few hours**, every time, **when I create a new component**, after I define the exact component and gives it content, **when I attempt to use it in the App.js**, or anywhere (after importation, of course), it **displays a few components, but not all**, either I refresh it.

**The only solution** is, if I **delete the closing bracket** of the **return statement**, **save** it, **wait for the error** on the development server, then **write it back**.

e.g.

```
function MainNavigation() {
return (
    <header>
        <div>React Meetups</div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">All Meetups</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/new-meetup">Add New Meetup</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/favorites">My Favorites</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
);
}
```

In this case, after ctrl+s, the dev. server displays the div, and the "All Meetups" list item with the link, but not the other two.
If i delete the **);** part of the statement, then save it, and write back, then save it again, only then will the changes appear.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Few problem which I can think of are as follow

1. Try to do hard refresh instead of deleting the ");"
2. Try to inspect the file from developer console. May be some css color ias same as background color.

Comment: I've tried the hard refresh a lot, but it doesn't work.

The developer console has a bunch of errors, until I delete the ");", but after that, it's clean.

Comment: @GaramvölgyiSoma can you please share the screen shot.